# SQL query optimization for sports matches

Tags: mysql

Hello i need to optimize my SQl query because at the moment i am asking too many queries when i run my code on my website.

What i need is the name of each team that is playing in a match. I currently have this :

> Match (idMatch, homeTeamId, awayTeamId)
>
> Team (idTeam, nameTeam)

my code currently cycles through each match getting both homeTeamId and awayTeamId and then performing the same query for each:

> SELECT nameTeam FROM Team WHERE idTeam = homeTeamId
> SELECT nameTeam FROM Team WHERE idTeam = awayTeamId

So thats 3 queries just to get a readable version of the match:

> 'homeTeam' vs 'awayTeam'.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me optmize the SQL query so either it could be compressed into a single query or optimized to take up less ressources.

Thank you

Comment: It would be useful to see the query in its entirety

Comment: There must be a thousand examples of this out there.

Comment: Yes i'm sure there are alot of these questions but i wasn't sure where to start looking. Sorry for adding another relativly easy question to the list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want but :

I think You can do :

```
Select m.idMatch, m.homeTeamId, th.homeTeamName, m.awayTeamId, ta.awayTeamName
FROM Match m
LEFT JOIN TEAM ta ON ta.idteam = m.awayteamId
LEFT JOIN TEAM th ON th.idteam = m.hometeamId
```

And you add `WHERE` clause you want.

Is that what you need?

This will give you for example:

```
match1 idTeam1 teamName1 idTeam2 teamName2
match2 idTeam2 teamName2 idTeam3 teamName3
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for thank you, sorry if it wasn't very clear.